# What could be causing this PHP page to work normally in WAMPServer, but not on a web server?

Tags: php, html, web-services

I made a HTML page in PHP to test a multilingual architecture and learn PHP.

A function in the file receives a language variable, paragraph number, sifts through a text file and returns the appropriate string.

I have been testing this locally and made sure it worked properly, but when I try this on my hosting service (making sure all paths and everything are unchanged), the script does not load and then a server error message appears.

I have also made sure that the version of PHP on my LAN and the version on the server match. (PHP Version 5.5.1.2).

What could be causing the program not to work?

**The PHP file looks like this**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PHP Test</title>
        <link style rel=stylesheet href="style.css" type="text/css">
    </head>
<?php

function skipLines($numberOfLanguages, $numberOfPairs, $openFile) {
    //for the number of pairs given, skip numOfLangs * 2
    //2 = one line for the numbers and one for the paragraph itself
    for ($x=0; $x < (($numberOfPairs - 1) * $numberOfLanguages * 2); $x = $x + 1) {
        //just casts them into the wind... like ashes
        fgets($openFile);
    }
}

function newRetriever($textPairNumber, $selectedLanguage, $openFile) {

    //3 = numberOfLanguages
    skipLines(3, $textPairNumber, $openFile);

    $languageFound = false;
    //test for language and return when true
    while ($languageFound == false) {

        //get the number and language in text after skipping is done
        $currentPlaceArray = explode(" ", fgets($openFile));
        $currentLanguage = $currentPlaceArray[1];

        if (strcmp($currentLanguage, $selectedLanguage) == 2) {
            $languageFound = true;
            echo utf8_decode(fgets($openFile));
        } else {
            fgets($openFile);
        }

    }

    //rewind
    rewind($openFile);
}
?>
<body>
<h1>Human Rights Declaration</h1>
<p>This page uses PHP to retrieve different copies of text from each language and places them appropriately.</p>
<p>
    <?php
        $f = fopen("rawtext4languages.txt", "r");
        newRetriever("3", "s", $f);
        fclose($f);
    ?>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The text file has this basic format, divided by line breaks:

```
1 e
Line in English
1 s
Line in Spanish
1 f
Line in French
1 g
Line in German
2 e
Line in English
(...) And so forth
```

Also, you can see how it responds on the server here:
http://www.eamonbohan.com/Exercises/PHP/phplesson1.php

Additionally, I got an answer from my hosting service that says this:

> Thank you for contacting our Help Desk.  During the initial
>   investigation of your issue we noticed that your script is executing
>   in 30 seconds timeout. We increased the timeout for it to 120 seconds,
>   but it did not help.  Here is the strace output of your script:

(Interjection: in the stack, there is an extra function I removed from the code above but it basically just builds a header based on the language variable. 0.000060 is the point in the strace output where things get weird).

```
eamonboh@eamonbohan.com [~/public_html/Exercises/PHP]# strace -s 2048 -r -p
`pgrep -u eamonboh php` 
Process 29025 attached - interrupt to quit
0.000000 restart_syscall(<... resuming interrupted call ...>) = 0
4.021723 write(1, " <body>\n <h1>Human Rights Declaration</h1>\n <p>This page uses PHP to retrieve different copies of text from each language and places them appropriately.</p>\n <p>\n ", 182) = 182
0.000244 getcwd("/home/eamonboh/public_html/Exercises/PHP", 4096) = 41
0.000199 lstat("/home/eamonboh/public_html/Exercises/PHP/rawtexttrilingual.txt", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3262, ...}) = 0
0.000359 open("/home/eamonboh/public_html/Exercises/PHP/rawtexttrilingual.txt", O_RDONLY) = 3
0.000125 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3262, ...}) = 0
0.000163 lseek(3, 0, SEEK_CUR) = 0
0.000060 write(1, "<h2>", 4) = 4
0.000054 write(1, "1st", 3) = 3
0.000038 write(1, " ", 1) = 1
0.000134 write(1, "Spanis", 6) = 6
0.000038 write(1, "h article</h2>", 14) = 14
0.000060 read(3, "1 e\nAll human beings are born free and equal in dignity and rights. They are endowed with reason and conscience and should act towards one another in a spirit of brotherhood.\n1 s\nTodos los seres humanos nacen libres e iguales en dignidad y derechos y, dotados como est\303\241n de raz\303\263n y conciencia, deben comportarse fraternalmente los unos con los otros.\n1 f\nTous les \303\252tres humains naissent libres et \303\251gaux en dignit\303\251 et en droits. Ils sont dou\303\251s de raison et de conscience et doivent agir les uns envers les autres dans un esprit de fraternit\303\251.\n2 e\nEveryone is entitled to all the rights and freedoms set forth in this Declaration, without distinction of any kind, such as race, colour, sex, language, religion, political or other opinion, national or social origin, property, birth or other status.</p<p>Furthermore, no distinction shall be made on the basis of the political, jurisdictional or international status of the country or territory to which a person belongs, whether it be independent, trust, non-self-governing or under any other limitation of sovereignty.\n2 s\nToda persona tiene los derechos y libertades proclamados en esta Declaraci\303\263n, sin distinci\303\263n alguna de raza, color, sexo, idioma, religi\303\263n, opini\303\263n pol\303\255tica o de cualquier otra \303\255ndole, origen nacional o social, posici\303\263n econ\303\263mica, nacimiento o cualquier otra condici\303\263n.</p><p>Adem\303\241s, no se har\303\241 distinci\303\263n alguna fundada en la condici\303\263n pol\303\255tica, jur\303\255dica o internacional del pa\303\255s o territorio de cuya jurisdicci\303\263n dependa una persona, tanto si se trata de un pa\303\255s independiente, como de un territorio bajo administraci\303\263n fiduciaria, no aut\303\263nomo o sometido a cualquier otra limitaci\303\263n de soberan\303\255a.\n2 f\nChacun peut se pr\303\251valoir de tous les droits et de toutes les libert\303\251s proclam\303\251s dans la pr\303\251sente D\303\251claration, sans distinction aucune, notamment de race, de couleur, de sexe, de langue, de religion, d'opinion politique ou de toute autre opinion, d'origine nationale ou sociale, de fortune, de naissance ou de toute autre situation.</p><p>D"..., 8192) = 3262
0.000269 read(3, "", 8192) = 0
120.032177 --- SIGPROF (Profiling timer expired) @ 0 (0) ---
0.000170 setitimer(ITIMER_PROF, {it_interval={0, 0}, it_value={120, 0}}, NULL) = 0
0.000134 rt_sigaction(SIGPROF, {0x810d70, [PROF], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f3369d02030}, {0x810d70, [PROF], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f3369d02030}, 8) = 0
0.000149 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [PROF], NULL, 8) = 0
0.000078 open("php_errorlog", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_APPEND, 0644) = 4
0.000224 write(4, "[12-Mar-2015 15:28:34 America/Chicago] PHP Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded in /home/eamonboh/public_html/Exercises/PHP/phplesson1.php on line 56\n", 174) = 174
0.000102 close(4) = 0
0.000076 write(1, "<br />\n<b>Fatal error</b>: Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded in <b>/home/eamonboh/public_html/Exercises/PHP/phplesson1.php</b> on line <b>56</b><br />\n", 165) = 165
0.000072 chdir("/home/eamonboh/public_html/Exercises/PHP") = 0
0.000048 setitimer(ITIMER_PROF, {it_interval={0, 0}, it_value={0, 0}}, NULL) = 0
0.000088 close(3) = 0
0.000277 --- SIGTERM (Terminated) @ 0 (0) ---
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated by this webdev newbie.

Comment: What line is 56 in the code you posted above?

Comment: Your link just displays `Hello there PHP"; ?>`

Comment: Hi @JohnConde, I am not sure what it would be since it is 55 lines long for me.

Comment: @PeterBowers, let me correct that. The file extension is PHP and not the dummy HTML, thanks for letting me know!

Comment: "Something went wrong with the site caching!" you broke the host

Comment: i think the while is an infinite loop. that's where i would concentrate my debugging

Comment: @Dagon, I went to check the code and at least on my LAN it ends every loop correctly. I know this because I added a statement signalling that it finished the while loop every time it did. Thanks for the suggestion though.